# работа с map контейнером

Tags: c++, map

Здравствуйте. Никогда раньше не использовал и не работал с контейнерами, а именно с `map`. В учебных целях есть необходимость взять файл и запихать его в контейнер. Собственно вот как я это делаю:

```
map<string, int> words;
ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open("text.txt");
string word;
while (inputfile >> word)
{
    words[word]++;
}
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("texto.txt");
int count = 0;
map<string, int>::iterator cursor;
outfile << "Now we have:" << endl;
for (cursor = words.begin(); cursor != words.end(); cursor++)
{
    outfile << (*cursor).first  << "\t\t: " << (*cursor).second << endl;
    cout << (*cursor).first << "\t\t: " << (*cursor).second << endl;
    count += (*cursor).second;
}
```

А теперь мне необходимо этот же файл загрузить в контейнер `<int string>`, но в переменной `int` будет хранится число гласных букв в каждом слове. Интересует, как описать этот алгоритм. Код за меня писать не прошу.

Comment: Может, всё-таки `<string,int>`? Тогда всё просто: считаем гласные в слове и пишем `<слово,гласные>`.

Comment: @klopp забыл упомянуть что контейнер должен быть отсортирован, и я не знаю принципа обращения к переменным контейнера. а map контейнер сортируется автоматически, на сколько мне известно.

Comment: Отсортирован по какому критерию? И всё-таки какой именно контейнер? `map<int,string>` как хранилище количества гласных в словах пока выглядит нелепо.

Comment: @klopp сортируется по первому ключу, и сортируется по алфавиту либо по убыванию. контейнер для гласных именно map<int,string>

Comment: Допустим, у нас есть набор слов: "bar", "baz", "biz". Что должно оказаться в контейнере, если ключом во всех трёх случаях будет 1?

Comment: Сформулируй более понятно что собственно нужно сделать. А то "будет хранится число гласных букв в каждом слове" намекает что это как бы уже дано, а на самом деле похоже что нет.

Answer (score 2):

Не хватает репутации для комментов, ибо лень было переносить аккаунт) Так что пишу сюда. Работал с этой штукой. Тебе должен помочь `std::multimap` - там у одного ключа может быть много значений. [ВОТ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1ka6hya8.aspx) посмотри.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно посчитать количество гласных букв в слове, то это делается так:

```
const std::string glb( "тут список только гласных букв" );
const std::string word( "слово" );
int count = 0; //здесь будет количество гласных
for( std::string::const_iterator i = word.begin(), e = word.end(); i != e; ++i )
   count += glb.find_first_of( *i ) != std::string::npos;
```

Comment: А не проще ли гласные хранить в `std::set` или `std::map`? Ну и `for( size_t i = 0; i < word.size(); i++ ) { /* проверили word[i] в set/map... */ }`

Comment: Не проще, в виде std::string это одна строчка, для set это несколько сложнее в плане заполнения. Если бы гласных было много, штук 100+, то это бы имело смысл - было бы эффективнее (быстрее) через set или лучше сортированный массив+двоичный поиск. А на малых массивах линейный поиск будет быстрее.